# Datatables: Position Search Box to the top right

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datatables

How do i position the search box to the right? By default it is to the left now

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Here is an example with the search box aligned to the right](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html).

It looks like they use this CSS style:

```
.dataTables_filter {
   width: 50%;
   float: right;
   text-align: right;
}
```

As far as I can tell, this is the default, which means you are probably doing something that is overriding this. Could you post an example where the field is improperly aligned so we can take a look at it?

Comment: All though this would work, its not the built in logic datatables has for moving its internal elements around. sDom is the method/object you wanna look into. But Im not knocking this method either as its far easier to do than sDom is (well its easier to understand). I would position the element as absolute though and dynamically position it via some math in some javascript. But thats me, not a huge fan of floating something like that.

Comment: As I understand it, [sDom](http://datatables.net/ref#sDom) controls whether it's in the header or footer of the table; I don't see anything in the API that suggests right/left alignment; did I miss something there? Additionally, the CSS class is directly from their examples.

Comment: @Kato - Thanks. It works now. What about the next/prev button? How do i move it to the right too?

Comment: In my case, I forget to include css and after including, it wokrs as expected