# Datatable search filter not aligning to the rightmost part of the table

Tags: css, datatables

The datatable search filter is not aligning to the rightmost part of the table.
Based on suggestions here:
[Datatables: Position Search Box to the top right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039021/datatables-position-search-box-to-the-top-right)

I tried changing the following lines in dataTables.bootstrap.css:
[image: Search box is not aligning to the rightmost part of the table.]

```
div.dataTables_filter {
   width: 50%;
   float: right;
   text-align: right;
}
```

but it still won't align correctly. I have also tried adding !important to each setting but it still will not change. Anybody know why? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried to play around with the style settings of my own datatable and I can align it by the left or by the right window edge.

So, I might assume, there may be something within your other stylesheets that overrides style settings for all div's (including those having class 'dataTables_filter').